# Laravel Extend Rule Message

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am using a 'unique' validation Rule within Laravel, which is currently within a FormRequest. I'm trying to customise the message returned from this Rule and I can't see in the documentation where Laravel generates this message.

I realise it is possible to fully extend the Validator and create my own custom one, but all I need to do is customise the 'Unique' rule message. The class in the documentation is [here:](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Validation/Rules/Unique.php)

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Validation/Rules/Unique.php

any pointers on where internally this message is generated? For reference this is the current output:

```
{
  "message": "422 Unprocessable Entity",
  "errors": {
    "user_id": [
      "The user id has already been taken."
    ]
  },
  "status_code": 422
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this in your Request class:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [ 
        'name' => 'unique'
    ]
}

public function messages()
{ 
     return[
         'name.unique' => 'Write your own message ... '
     ]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

. Use the messages() function to overwrite them

Function messages in your request file

```
    'email.required' => 'Er, you forgot your email address!',
    'email.unique' => 'Email already taken m8',
```